# Why does this JSON object return backslashes? And how do I get rid of them?

Tags: javascript, json

Why does this JSON object return backslashes?

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xf7F14205898b2b8bC008148E591B1060BE7a50Fb&apikey=DFMRS7RGGBAZW3ZDKEQTRVMBCA87JVSQVT

And how do I get rid of them? Furthermore, how do I get rid of the header status code?

I created a javascript fetch object that fetches the URL and parses it then returns the object in react as a string, but this is unusable in the current context.

The JSON object returns such 
`{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":"[{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"findPercentage\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}]`

But I need it without the header and to return it a newline as such...

```
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Call `JSON.parse()` on the `result` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is a JSON string which contains 3 properties when parsed: a message, a status, and a result. That result property's value is *another* JSON string, so you need to parse it as well, and you'll have a well-formed object to work with:

```js
fetch('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xf7F14205898b2b8bC008148E591B1060BE7a50Fb&apikey=DFMRS7RGGBAZW3ZDKEQTRVMBCA87JVSQVT')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((responseObj) => {
    const trueObj = JSON.parse(responseObj.result);
    console.log(trueObj);
  });
```

Keep in mind that [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). If you have an object or array, then you have an object or array, full stop. JSON format is a *method of representing an object in a string*, like `const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}'`.

Comment: Just to be clear, the anonymous function here returns an array? What I'm seeing in the console is an array with 30 items. How would I use it or convert it where an object is needed? Such as new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface[, address][, options])

Comment: `.json()` returns a Promise that resolves to the `JSON.parse`d version of whatever the endpoint returns. It may be an array or object, or it may be a string, etc.

Comment: If you only need one item in the array, access the index of the array that you want to extract, eg `trueObj[0]`